# Debug XMPP Android client with aSmack, Eclipse and the enhanced debugger.

Tags: android, eclipse, xmpp, smack, asmack

I'm making an application with the Android XMPP library [aSmack](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack) with Eclipse. I can not get debug is launched in a separate window as instructed smack documentation:

http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/debugging.html

I imported smackx-debug.jar inside the libs folder and I've added this line to the code:

Connection.DEBUG_ENABLED = false;

The debug occurs, but in console of logcat, not a Enhanced Debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aSmack is not able to use the enhanced debugger of smack. It's not possible that the Android app draws a new window on your PC running eclipse.

Instead all XMPP traffic is logged to the Android log and can be viewed with DDMS or `adb shell logcat`.

Comment: @Flow Any specific method callback from receiver side once file downloaded successfully instead check all the time in while loop ? i know that could be another question  :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using smack 4.3.0 
Enable debugging in the logcat with

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setXmppDomain(mServiceName)
            .setHost(mServiceName)
            .setResource("Rooster+")

            .setSendPresence(true)
            .enableDefaultDebugger()
```

.enableDefaultDebugger(), this sorted me out