# Adding Enhanced Debugger to view packet level information for Smack android based XMPP client

Tags: android, ubuntu, debugging, xmpp, smack

I'm referring to https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.0/documentation/debugging.html for integrating debugger console in my android studio and added SmackConfiguration.DEBUG = true; but still can't see any debugging window.
Please help me in this.

**Edited [08-Feb-2018]:**

On the basis of smack debugging document (https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/debugging.md)

we can show all the packet level information in logcat or in system console.

For console logs:

```
 System.setProperty("smack.debuggerClass", "org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.ConsoleDebugger")
 System.setProperty("smack.debugEnabled", "true")
```

For Android Logcat:

```
SmackConfiguration.DEBUG = true
```

However, as per the doc, it provides GUI debugger viz [Lite Debugger](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/debugging.md#lite-debugger) and [Enhanced Debugger](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/debugging.md#enhanced-debugger)

Viewing multiple unorganized XMPP logs aren't readable at all. It will be however convenient to read via a GUI Debugger like the enhanced debugger.

I am using Ubuntu (Linux OS) and Android Studio for the development.

**How can we add GUI debugger for debugging for building an android client?**

Comment: I am trying to do the same. Where you ever able to figure it out? @user2660386

Comment: There was no individual window for it,but i could see logs in verbose.

Comment: how did you access the logs? what did you type to search thru the logs for smack debugging? @user2660386

Comment: if you have SmackConfiguration.DEBUG = true in your code , then you can see smack related logs in logcat

Comment: [Checkout this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913253/1457696) This solved my issues with debugging

Comment: [Checkout this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913253/1457696) This will print out smack traffic in the log cat

Answer (score 1):

Set system property like this:

```
System.setProperty("smack.debuggerClass","org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.ConsoleDebugger");
System.setProperty("smack.debugEnabled", "true");
SmackConfiguration.DEBUG = true;
```

Comment: Yes, this works. It would print all smack traffic in the logcat as system.out